# ImageMagick.net issues

Tags: c#, imagemagick

I am using ImageMagick.net and I have added **ImageMagickNET.dl** reference to my project. This is the code is I am using.

```
MagickNet.Magick.Init();
MagicNet.Image img = new MagicNet.Image("file.jpg");
img.Resize(System.Drawing.Size(100,100));
img.Write("newFile.png");
MagickNet.Magick.Term();
```

But I am getting this error "'ImageMagickNET.MagickNet' does not contain a definition for 'Magick'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oups, try this I test it it works:

```
    using System;
using M = MagickNet;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            M.Magick.Init();
            M.Image img = new M.Image("file.jpg");
            img.Resize(new Size(100, 100));
            img.Write("newFile.png");
            MagickNet.Magick.Term();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not working for me, OK i just downloaded imageMagick.net and added the  ImageMagickNET.dll reference to my project.  is there any step i am missing ?.

Comment: i have download 1.0.0.3 version and i set Framework 2.0 on properties target framework

Comment: How to change that. I am using visual studio 2010

Comment: can you please send that download link ..?

Comment: I think i am using different version can you please send the download link that u downloaded.

Comment: Happy to help you Vijesh and congratulations ;-)