# c# Converting all image formats to JPG

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looking for solution to "converting all image formats to JPG".

My current code:

```
    public ActionResult UploadProfilFotografi(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        int sessionUID = int.Parse(Session["UID"].ToString());
        using (var dbContext = new DB_EMafya())
        {
            if (file != null
                && file.ContentLength > 1
                && file.ContentLength < 5120
                && myFunction.IsImage(file))
            {
                var users = dbContext
                    .tbl_Users
                    .FirstOrDefault(a => a.UID == sessionUID);

                if (users != null)
                {
                    string newPicName = (string) Session["UID"];
                    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                    if (extension != null)
                    {
                        string picext = extension.ToLower();
                        string originalpath = Path.Combine(
                            Server.MapPath("~/up/profile-pictures/originals"),
                            newPicName + picext);

                        // file is uploaded
                        file.SaveAs(originalpath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("ProfilAyarlari", "Profil");
    }
```

**Could you help on this please?**

**I find a solution:**
[c# convert image formats to jpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894836/c-sharp-convert-image-formats-to-jpg)

I edited some and added some more values to function. And put codes inside to using.

```
    private void SaveAsJpgWithVaryQualityLevel(HttpPostedFileBase file, string toPath, string fileName)
    {
        using (var target = new MemoryStream())
        {
            file.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
            using (var bmp1 = new Bitmap(target)) // Get a bitmap.
            {
                var jgpEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                var myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;
                using (var myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1))
                {
                    using (var myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100L))
                    {
                        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
                        bmp1.Save(@"" + toPath + fileName, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
    {
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
        return codecs.FirstOrDefault(codec => codec.FormatID == format.Guid);
    }
```

**Calling:**

```
string newPicName = Convert.ToString(Session["UID"]) + ".jpg";
string toPath = Server.MapPath("~/_up/profile-pictures/originals/");
SaveAsJpgWithVaryQualityLevel(file, toPath, newPicName); // file is uploaded
```

Comment: How is that code related to ... anything? It doesn't do any type of conversion. What have you tried for the *conversion* portion of your question? Also, why do you care that everything is JPG? Several other formats work on the web. If they *must* be JPG, why isn't this enforced on upload?

Comment: Dear debracey, I would like to converts all images to jpg because, I just want to know all uploads by user, JPG format. And I'm new on it. Btw @BartoszKP, thanks for editting. Regards

Comment: have a look here to get you started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807971/imagemagick-net-issues

Comment: Hi rene, thanks for your respond. I don't want to use library for a convert. I think library == extra load. But I'm going to try. Thanks. Regards

Comment: Its goodto say RENAMING instead of conversion.

Comment: @ErçinDedeoğlu library == likely more reliable code than a beginner will write. Check out [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/) and be done with this part of your project in a day.

Comment: @ErçinDedeoğlu [Good reading](http://www.nathanaeljones.com/blog/2009/20-image-resizing-pitfalls)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this code will help you :

ImageFormat is a class of System.Drawing.Imaging

```
public Image BitmapToBytes(HttpPostedFileBase file, ImageFormat p_Format)
{

BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
byte[] binData = b.ReadBytes(file.InputStream.Length);

Image imageObject =  new Bitmap(MemoryStream(binData));

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
imageObject.Save(stream, p_Format);

return new Bitmap(stream);
}
```