# Convert any image format to JPG

Tags: c#

I have a web app that runs on Azure. The user can upload an image and I save that image for them. Now when I receive the image, I have it as `byte[]`. I would like to save it as `JPG` to save space. The source image could be anything such as PNG, BMP or JPG.

Is it possible to do so? This needs to run on Azure and I am using WebApps/MVC5/C#.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# Converting all image formats to JPG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948551/c-sharp-converting-all-image-formats-to-jpg)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The method BitmapToBytes in the above link might be the solution. It worked locally. I am deploying to Azure to test it. Will get back with the result.

Comment: @mjwills thank you that method worked on Azure too. I uploaded a png 1.7 meg and saved to azure blob as jpg 213kb. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the memorystream and then use System.Drawing

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray)
Image img =  new Bitmap(stream);
img.Save(@"c:\s\pic.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

The last line there where you save the file, you can select the format.

Comment: Cody thank you. Yes that is very similar to the link posted above. I will mark yours as a solution but will post the exact two methods as another solution. Cheers.

Comment: Is there a method to convert image format without saving it to disk? like change format in memory stream and then save to database.

Answer (score 2):

So the answers by @mjwills and Cody was correct. I still thought to put the two methods I exactly needed:

```
    public static Image BitmapToBytes(byte[] image, ImageFormat pFormat)
    {
        var imageObject = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(image));

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        imageObject.Save(stream, pFormat);

        return new Bitmap(stream);
    }
```

Also:

```
    public static byte[] ImgToByteArray(Image img)
    {
        using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(mStream, img.RawFormat);
            return mStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Cheers everyone.