# Convert IFormFile image .png to .jpg in .Net 5

Tags: image, .net-5, image-compression

it's possible to convert IFormFile image with .png extension to .jpg? Is because the .png size is higher than .jpg, and when I save it in blob storage, it take a lot of time.

I'm using .Net 5

Comment: you want to convert the image dynamically after receiving in your controller before saving to blob storage. right ? is yes then try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51509496/9247039)